# How to get the history of an NFT or NFT Series from blockfrost?

Tags: transaction, nft, blockfrost, transaction-history

Hi is there a quick API call to get the transaction history of a specific NFT or collection of NFTs in BlockFrost?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, there’s an endpoint for the asset transactions here:

[https://docs.blockfrost.io/#tag/Cardano-Assets/paths/~1assets~1{asset}~1transactions/get](https://docs.blockfrost.io/#tag/Cardano-Assets/paths/%7E1assets%7E1%7Basset%7D%7E1transactions/get)

and also one for mint & burning history here:

[https://docs.blockfrost.io/#tag/Cardano-Assets/paths/~1assets~1{asset}~1history/get](https://docs.blockfrost.io/#tag/Cardano-Assets/paths/%7E1assets%7E1%7Basset%7D%7E1history/get)

Comment: {asset}=nft asset id ?

Comment: Yes it’s the policy id combined with the hex encoded asset name, simply concatenated.
Example from the docs:

b0d07d45fe9514f80213f4020e5a61241458be626841cde717cb38a76e7574636f696e

Comment: is there a quick way to get the hex-encoded assetname?

Comment: You can just strip off the first 56 characters and you're left with the hex encoded asset name, eg using substring: asset.substring(56)

Answer (score 2):

combination of the policy_id and hex encoded asset_name needs to be provided as an input parameter for this endpoint:
[Blockfrost - Specific Asset](https://docs.blockfrost.io/#tag/Cardano-Assets/paths/%7E1assets%7E1%7Basset%7D/get)